# 400 Bad Request when attempting to import CSV file into Google Drive Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api, data-conversion

I am using [Drive API files/create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) to upload  a file to Google Drive. Everything is fine as long as I don't specify the `mimeType`, or anything except `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`.

Here is my request:

[image]

The response is 400 with not so useful body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I tried setting the `mimeType` to `text/csv`, it works fine. I even tried requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about, and funnily they list my import as valid:

```
"text/csv": [
  "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
],
```

but in reality it is not. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: About ``import CSV file into Google Drive Spreadsheet``, you want to put the values of a CSV file to the existing Spreadsheet? Or you want to create the uploaded CSV file as new Spreadsheet? Or you want to update the existing Spreadsheet using CSV file with Drive API? By the way, can you provide your current script?

Comment: It's a totally new file (as you can see, I am using `files/create` endpoint). The script is a bit complicated (we have common methods for adding Headers etc), but basically it produces the request as you can see above, and you can reproduce the problem with that info already.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I propose 2 modification points. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Although I'm not sure about your script and the CSV data, from your request body, I propose 2 modification points as follows. Can you modify the following points and try to run again? I propose to remove `;` of the last letter of the following 2 lines.

#### From:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8;
```

#### To:

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

And

#### From:

```
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8;
```

#### To:

```
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: To anyone who doubts this answer, I didn't believe this would work. Nevertheless, no harm in trying, and indeed it works... Thank you.

Comment: @Luke Vo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.